# "It was very unfortunate of him..." Is the preposition "of" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adjectives, collocation

> It was very unfortunate of him to have lost the battle.

In this sentence, is the usage of the preposition "of" correct?

Answer (score 8):

A more natural preposition to use in this context would be "for".

> "It was very unfortunate for him to have lost the battle."

Using "of" would seem more natural in a sentence such as, "it was very rude of him to have said that". The difference seems to be that being rude is something one does more actively, whereas being unfortunate is something that happens to one. Compare, "that was very kind of him," and "that was lucky for him."

One way to sidestep the problem entirely would be to use a relative clause, with an optional phrase indicating whose misfortune we are concerned with:

> "It was very unfortunate (for whomever) that he lost the battle."

Comment: Yes. With a word like "responsible", the choice of *for* and *of* would indicate different meanings. "It was responsible of John to think of the child's needs" but "John was responsible for the child's welfare".

Comment: I agree that _of_ would not work here. But there are two different parses with _for_, with different meanings. One is "What was unfortunate for him? To have lost the battle"; the other is "What was unfortunate? For him to have last the battle". The first says it was unfortunate for him, but not necessarily for the rest of us - we could say this even if we were on the other side. The second says it's unfortunate in general.

Comment: @ColinFine , I agree, which is why I suggested the second sentence, with the relative clause.

Comment: I think the reason that "of" sounds awkward in this context is that fortune is relative.  What's unfortunate for party A may be fortunate for party B.  By saying "unfortunate of him," it is unclear who is actually experiencing the misfortune. An omniscient narrator?

Answer (score 1):

*Of* and *for* are used in  two different constructions.

- The *(very) `Adjective` of `Noun Phrase`* construction, like *very rude/kind of you*,
  attributes `Adjective` to `Noun Phrase`, which implies in this case that *you are rude/kind*.
  (at least in the view of the speaker).
- The *for `Noun Phrase` to `Verb Phrase`*, or Complete Infinitive, construction.
  Since infinitives are verbs, they have to have subjects, even if the subjects don't appear
  in the infinitive clause.  But sometimes their subjects do appear, and occasionally the
  subject noun phrase is marked with *for*, just as the infinitive verb phrase is marked with *to*.

*Very unfortunate of/for him to have lost the battle* can be broken up two ways:

1. *(It was) [Very unfortunate of him] [to have lost the battle]*
   This can be transformed into
   *[To have lost the battle] was [very unfortunate of him]*
   This attributes the predicate adjective *unfortunate* to the pronoun *him*.
2. *(It was) [Very unfortunate] [for him to have lost the battle]*
   This can be transformed into
   *[For him to have lost the battle] was [very unfortunate]*
   This attributes *unfortunate* to the infinitive clause *for him to have lost the battle*.